# How to log exception to file

Tags: c#

I have been trying to log exceptions to a file. I can get the exception with all its details and when I step through the class the `StreamWriter logWriter` doesn't seem to do what I thought it would do.

```
 public static void Write(Exception exception)
{
    string logfile = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        logfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLog"]).ToString();
        StreamWriter logWriter;
        if (File.Exists(logfile))
        {
            logWriter = File.AppendText(logfile);
        }
        else
        {
            logWriter = File.CreateText(logfile);
            logWriter.WriteLine("=>" + DateTime.Now + " " + " An Error occurred: " + exception.StackTrace +
                                " Message: " + exception.Message + "\n\n");
            logWriter.Close();
            throw exception;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

I would of thought the logWriter would of written the exception details to the File.AppendText(logfile)`but it doesn't and just jumps straight out the if statement. All the details of the exception are in the else statement, I have tried to put this in the`if` condition but throws an exception!

How can I write the exception to the file. I got the code from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550510/Exception-Handling-and-NET). Everything thing works fine except writing the exception to the file.

Comment: what is the value of `logfile`? - have you added the `ErrorLog` appsetting correctly?

Comment: Why not just move the lines where you write to the files outside the if/else entirely. It seems the only conditional thing you need to do is decide wheter to Create of Append.

Comment: Why don't you use an logging framework like Serilog to log your exceptions and information instead of reinventing the wheel. Just a thought.

Comment: logfile holds the path to the file to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it correctly and throw the exception outside of the method:

```
public static void Write(Exception exception)
{
    string logfile = String.Empty;
        try
    {
        logfile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLog"]).ToString();

        if(File.Exists(logfile))
        {
            using(var writer = new StreamWriter(logfile, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(
                    "=>{0} An Error occurred: {1}  Message: {2}{3}", 
                    DateTime.Now, 
                    exception.StackTrace, 
                    exception.Message, 
                    Environment.NewLine
                    );
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Throw it outside:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Write(e);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works to write into a file

```
public static bool WriteResult(string result)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText("result.txt"))
            {
                sr.WriteLine(result);
                sr.Flush();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

For you, you have to adapt it a bit to meet your requirments :

```
public static void Write(Exception exception) {
    try {

        using(StreamWriter sr = File.AppendText("result.txt")) //new StreamWriter("result.txt", Encoding. ))
        {

            sr.WriteLine("=>" + DateTime.Now + " " + " An Error occurred: " + exception.StackTrace +
                " Message: " + exception.Message + "\n\n");
            sr.Flush();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please try an format your code better, what you have posted is hard to read.

Answer (score -1):

A nice template method i wrote goes with every project.

```
  private static void AddLog(string strMsg)
    {

        #region logfolder creation
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\appname"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\appname");
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\appname\\Logs"))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\appname\\Logs");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region logfile creation
        FileStream fsc;
        logFileName = "C:\\appname\\Logs\\appnameLog_" + DateTime.Now.Year + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Day + ".txt";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(logFileName))
        {
            fsc = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            fsc.Close();
        }
        #endregion
        #region logging

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                try
                {
                    sr.WriteLine(strMsg);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    EventLogEntry(exc.ToString().Trim(), EventLogEntryType.Error, 7700);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: _"Here is the code I use in a similar situation"_ isn't really a good answer to _"Why doesn't my code work?"_, especially when the code you post has a lot of issues.

Comment: @CodeCaster what kind of issues ?

Comment: Issues are: using regions (don't), you can call `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\appname\\Logs");` immediately (8 lines to 1), you can instantiate a `StreamWriter` with `append` to `true` so it'll create the file if it doesn't exist _or_ append to the existing file, the `EventLogEntry()` method doesn't exist, there's more that can fail that doesn't have a try-catch clause and this will fail when used in a multithreading environment. Just use log4net.